# Вывод команды через переменную в консоль. bash

Tags: linux, bash

мне надо вывести команду через переменную в консоль, как это сделать я понимаю:

```
a=$(uname -r)
echo $a
```

А если у меня есть несколько команд и мне нужно при запуске скрипта указать, что мне нужно вывести только одну из них, например для вывода только kernel:

```
./script.sh -k
--------
kernel=5.13.0-28-generic
```

Или например запустить скрипт с -h для help, как я могу это реализовать? Спасибо!

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/326328/ `Ключи командной строки` ?

Answer (score 1):

можно взять к примеру шаблон из https://devhints.io/bash (см. Getting options)  и немного адаптировать под наши нужды

так выглядит сам шаблон:

```
while [[ "$1" =~ ^- && ! "$1" == "--" ]]; do case $1 in
  -V | --version )
    echo $version
    exit
    ;;
  -s | --string )
    shift; string=$1
    ;;
  -f | --flag )
    flag=1
    ;;
esac; shift; done
if [[ "$1" == '--' ]]; then shift; fi
```

пример script.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

help="Использование: script [ПАРАМЕТР]...
Печатает определенные сведения о системе.
..."

a=$(uname -r)

while [[ "$1" =~ ^- && ! "$1" == "--" ]]; do case $1 in
  -h | --help   ) echo -e "$help"; exit;;
  -k | --kernel ) echo "$a"      ; exit;;
esac; shift; done
if [[ "$1" == '--' ]]; then shift; fi

exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предложил более простую передачу параметров скрипту c использованием встроенной функции работы с переменными:

```
#./script.sh
a=$(uname ${@:--r})
echo $a
```

Как это работает:

```
${a:-b}
^^||||^ Экранирование переменной с возможностью дополнительной обработки
  ^|||  Наименование переменной
   ^^|  Условие если переменная пустая
     ^  Значение если предыдущее условие соблюдено
```

Более подробно можно прочитать тут:  [gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Из чего следует, что если не передавать параметр(ы) скрипту, то по умолчанию подставится  параметр `-r`
(`bash -x` это дебаг режим выполнения скрипта)

```
# bash -x ./script.sh
++ uname -r       #сформированная команда
5.4.0-1093-gcp    #результат выполнения
```

Если скрипту передать параметр или несколько параметров то в обработку попадут именно они:

```
# bash -x ./script.sh -p -o
++ uname -p -o    #сформированная команда
x86_64 GNU/Linux  #результат выполнения
```

Comment: Когда же я уже научусь смотреть на даты вопроса)))